# Controlling the convergence of a series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that each $a_n$ is positive and  the $a_n$s decrease monotonically with limit zero. Is there any way to control the convergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{in\varphi} a_n$$
for $\varphi \in \mathbb R \setminus 2\pi \mathbb Z$?

It looks like most of the assumptions to apply Dirichlet's test hold, but I cannot control the sum of the $e^{in\varphi}$ in a good way to ensure the criterion applies. Other tests that I know fail. I also thought this looks like the Fourier series of some function, but I am not sure whether there exist results from the general theory that might help. I also do not see any good counterexample: each sequence $(a_n)$ I can think of yields either a trivial or a very complicated series. This looks like a very natural series to consider, but I have not found much online on it.

Comment: Dirichlet's criterion works, $$\sum_{n = 0}^k e^{in\varphi}$$ is a geometric sum. In the geometric sum formula, estimate the numerator brutally. The denominator is independent of $k$, thus you get a bound — depending on $\varphi$, but not on $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy enough to show that the partial sums of $e^{in \varphi}$ are bounded. In particular, we have
$$
\left|\sum_{n=0}^N e^{in \varphi}\right| = \left|\sum_{n=0}^N (e^{i \varphi})^n\right| = \left|\frac{e^{i(N+1)\varphi} - 1}{e^{i \varphi} - 1}\right| \leq 
\frac{|e^{i(N+1)\varphi}| + |1|}{\left|e^{i \varphi} - 1\right|} = \frac{2}{\left|e^{i \varphi} - 1\right|}.
$$
So, Dirichlet's test can be applied.

Comment: So simple that I did not see it...! Thank you.